# Swift iOS -How to scroll Sticky Header to top of screen when there aren't any cells inside CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

FYI this question is for manual scrolling when the user swipes up to see more cells.

I followed [this tutorial](https://sexyswift.wordpress.com/2016/08/23/sticky-header-of-uicollectionview/) and made a sticky header.

Everything works fine and the sticky header scrolls to the top of the screen underneath the Nav Bar when the CollectionView has enough cells inside of it to fill up the entire screen (hypothetically 50 or more cells).

[image: Sticky Header Scroll to top of screen since there are cells]

**The problem is when there aren't any cells inside of the CollectionView or the number of cells is less then the height of the screen (ie. 1 or 2 cells) then the sticky header won't scroll to the top of the screen underneath the Nav Bar. It stays put.**

[image: Sticky Header won't scroll to the top of screen since there aren't any class inside of it.]

**How can I get the sticky header to scroll to the top of the scene underneath the Nav Bar when there aren't any cells inside of it or if the amount of cells is less then the screens height?**

[image: Sticky Header stills scroll to the top screen even though there aren't any cells inside of it]

Code below:

This is for the white cell above the sticky header that will scroll outside of the screen when the sticky header is scrolled to the top:

```
class WhiteCellAboveStickyHeader: UICollectionViewCell{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white

        // height is configured to 200 inside the collectionView's sizeForItemAt IndexPath
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This is for the cells below the sticky header that make it scroll to the top of the screen when there are enough cells:

```
class BlueCellBelowStickyHeader: UICollectionViewCell{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .blue

        // height is configured to 50 inside the collectionView's sizeForItemAt IndexPath
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This is the headerView for the sticky header:

```
class StickyHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

    let header: UIView = {
        let header = UIView()
        header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return header
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .orange

        addSubview(header)
        header.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        header.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        header.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        header.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Class with CollectionView:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let whiteCellAboveStickyHeader = "WhiteCellAboveStickyHeader"
let blueCellBelowStickyHeader = "BlueCellBelowStickyHeader"
let stickyHeader = "StickyHeader"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationItem.title = "Nav Bar"

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.register(WhiteCellAboveStickyHeader.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: whiteCellAboveStickyHeader)
    collectionView.register(BlueCellBelowStickyHeader.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: blueCellBelowStickyHeader)
    collectionView.register(StickyHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: stickyHeader)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    // These 2 lines are what makes the sticky header sticky
    let stickyHeaderLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    stickyHeaderLayout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // this is for the white cell above the sticky header
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        }

        /*
         -this is for the blue cell below the sticky header
         -since there aren't any cells underneath the sticky header it won't scroll to the top of the screen
         -if this number is 50 it will scroll to the top
        */
        return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // this is for the white cell above the sticky header
        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            let whiteCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: whiteCellAboveStickyHeader, for: indexPath) as! WhiteCellAboveStickyHeader
            return whiteCell
        }

        //  this is for the blue cell below the sticky header
        let blueCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: blueCellBelowStickyHeader, for: indexPath)  as! BlueCellBelowStickyHeader
        return blueCell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // this is for the white cell above the sticky header
    if indexPath.section == 0{
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
    }

    // this is for the blue cells underneath the sticky header
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    // this is for the cell above the sticky header
    if section == 0{
        return 0
    }

    // this is for the spacing between blue cells underneath the sticky header
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView{

        // since only 1 section will have a header in it then only return this

        var header: UICollectionReusableView?

        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader{

            header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: self.stickyHeader, for: indexPath) as! StickyHeader
        }

        return header!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        // if section is above sticky header make its height 0 so there won't be a header
        if section == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        }

        // for section header which is the StickyHeader configure it's height
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
}

}
```

AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        window?.rootViewController = navVC

        return true
    }

...
```